# Why does prestashop project migrated from website to localhost redirect to website?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have cloned a whole online website built with prestashop by FTP and hosted it on a XAMPP.
I have downloaded the SQL dump and imported it locally with phpMyAdmin. 
I have changed the conf files to use the local database.

When I go to localhost/myProject it redirects me to the website url. Why is that ? is there another configuration setting to edit? I have already looked in the conf table in database and domain URL was already set to "localhost", even on the online version.

Update : I found a reference to the website in table "ps_shop_url". I changed its values to localhost, now when I go to localhost it tells me "this page has an infinite redirection loop"

Comment: Grep your SQL dump to see if there's a reference to the live URL? You might be able to get away with fixing it in your data.

Comment: I think @halfer is right, the store domain & url is stored in db.

Comment: I don't know Prestashop, but also consider emptying any caches it might have.

Comment: There are plenty of guides for how to migrate a Prestashop install, a Google search for `moving prestashop` turns up  e.g. http://danilodellaquila.com/blog/change-or-move-prestashop-site-domain-name

Comment: I could find references only in "connections" which I assume is connection history so nothing weird about that.
I found also some references in ps_connections_source like this :
http_referer : http://localhost/prestashop/index.php request_uri : website.com/prestashop/index.php?controlle..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In **ps_shop_url** table you must set `domain=localhost`, `domain_ssl=localhost` & `physical_uri=/myProject/`

In **ps_configuration** set `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` & `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` to `localhost`

Also go at BackOffice -> Preferences -> SEO & URLs and click [Save] - this will regenerate your **.htaccess** file and will add the /myProject/ where needed.

That should be all.

Comment: Pay attention to the final slash on physical_uri

Comment: Where do you find "ps_shop_url"? 
I found ps_configuration table in my database and changes PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL & PS_SHOP_DOMAIN to localhost, but I can not find ps_shop_url...

Comment: You can edit these values in the admin area without touching the database

Comment: Do you need to specify the port used anywhere in the database? eg `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to the answer provided by prestashop-developer-com

For Prestashop 1.6, you just need to change the table **ps_shop_url** following the recommendation from prestashop-developer-com